# Execute cURL via PHP shell_exec() return different response than Execute cURL via Command Line

Tags: php, macos, shell, unix, curl

## I ran

a cURL on my Terminal

**Note** : state = b4cf8fe7-aa68-4b25-8f9a-03a67fb420c7

```
curl -c session_cookies.txt "https://login.uat.site.be/openid/oauth/authorize?client_id=site&state=b4cf8fe7-aa68-4b25-8f9a-03a67fb420c7&nonce5ba13e5f-256d-425d-808b-1e05d2aa3d72&response_type=code&claims=%7B%22id_token%22%3A%7B%22http%3A%2F%2Fsite.be%2Fclaims%2Froles%22%3Anull%7D%7D" 2>/dev/null| curl -v -b session_cookies.txt -L -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -v -d 'j_username=manager-sitelogin@gmail.com&j_password=site1' "https://login.uat.site.be/openid/login.do" 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep Location | grep code=
```

---

I got this reponse back

```
< Location: https://testserver.sitenets.com/user/secure/dashboard?code=zvk495dsnq1ycLKZgN8oqfFxQogg2oql&state=b4cf8fe7-aa68-4b25-8f9a-03a67fb420c7
```

**Note** : state = b4cf8fe7-aa68-4b25-8f9a-03a67fb420c7

---

## PHP

**Note** : state = b4cf8fe7-aa68-4b25-8f9a-03a67fb420c7

```
$cmd = 'curl -c session_cookies.txt "https://login.uat.site.be/openid/oauth/authorize?client_id=site&state=b4cf8fe7-aa68-4b25-8f9a-03a67fb420c7&nonce5ba13e5f-256d-425d-808b-1e05d2aa3d72&response_type=code&claims=%7B%22id_token%22%3A%7B%22http%3A%2F%2Fsite.be%2Fclaims%2Froles%22%3Anull%7D%7D" 2>/dev/null| curl -v -b session_cookies.txt -L -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -v -d 'j_username=manager-sitelogin@gmail.com&j_password=site1' "https://login.uat.site.be/openid/login.do" 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep Location | grep code=';


$result = shell_exec($cmd);

dd($result);
```

---

> **Note** : state != b4cf8fe7-aa68-4b25-8f9a-03a67fb420c7
>
> **Note** : state = 12345678-256d-425d-808b-1e05d2aa3d72

```
< Location: https://testserver.sitenets.com/user/secure/dashboard?code=zvk495dsnq1ycLKZgN8oqfFxQogg2oql&state=12345678-256d-425d-808b-1e05d2aa3d72
```

When I run `shell_exec($cmd)`, my state always come back different the one that I submitted. How is this possible?

Is it caching somewhere on my local machine? Should I clear something?

Why `shell_exec()` return slightly different result than if I would have do it directly on Terminal? I even tried using `exec()`, same result.

Comment: for `$cmd = 'curl -c session_cookies.txt ...` the session_cookies file must be in the program's current working directory. Is that the case also when you execute the php code?

Comment: I hope those aren't real usernames/password first of all second you may be having an issue with how you are running the script.  session_cookies.txt may be different because it appears you are running the command as the php server user not as your terminal user so maybe it is in different locations.

Comment: Is it just me or are you getting the nonce back? Can't be a coincidence.

Comment: @fvu : Good observation !!, I run that shell_exec in 1 of my controller, and the session.txt is in my public/ directory. I guess, I should include the absolute path to my session.txt ??? what do you think ?

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond : Thanks for remind me, I update the post. Since you and have the same suggestion and observation, I guess, I'll look into that.

Comment: That's definitely worth a try. Also, don't forget that [curl is available as an extension in php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), you are not obliged to shell out.

Comment: @apokryfos : You have really good eyes, Yes, it is my nonce, I paste that in by accident while constructing this post, but in real situation, it is not the nonce, it should be different number. I will update my post, and tweak it a little bit just to avoid the confusion. I'm sorry for this confusion.

Comment: @ihue I just pointed it out because I thought the server (somehow) confused the state with the nonce but if that's not what's happening then I don't know.

Comment: @fvu : Thanks for directing to the PHP curl, I've tried that 2 days ago, and I went through nightmare : http://stackoverflow.com/q/41855264/4480164

Comment: try using absolute path for session_cookies.txt in both cases.